# Incorrect value with python multiprocessing.Pool with Red Hat Satellite API

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Red Hat Satellite API to create Groups for RHEL4,5,6 systems. Without multiprocessing it works fine but I want to speedup the process so thought of using the multiprocessing.Pool but somehow getting incorrect value. Here is my code:

```
CLIENT = xmlrpclib.Server(SATELLITE_URL, verbose=0)
KEY = CLIENT.auth.login(SATELLITE_LOGIN, SATELLITE_PASSWORD)

def ADD_SYSTEMS(ITEM):
    SYSTEMID = ITEM['id']
    SYSTEMNAME = ITEM['name']
    RUNNINGKERNEL = CLIENT.system.getRunningKernel(KEY,SYSTEMID)
    print type(RUNNINGKERNEL), RUNNINGKERNEL, multiprocessing.current_process().name
    if RUNNINGKERNEL.startswith("2.6.32"):
    CLIENT.systemgroup.addOrRemoveSystems(KEY,"ALL_RHEL6_SYSTEMS",SYSTEMID,True)
    elif RUNNINGKERNEL.startswith("2.6.18"):
    CLIENT.systemgroup.addOrRemoveSystems(KEY,"ALL_RHEL5_SYSTEMS",SYSTEMID,True)
    else:
    CLIENT.systemgroup.addOrRemoveSystems(KEY,"ALL_RHEL4_SYSTEMS",SYSTEMID,True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ACTIVESYSTEMS = CLIENT.system.listActiveSystems(KEY)
    PSIZE = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    P = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PSIZE)
    P.map(ADD_SYSTEMS, ACTIVESYSTEMS)
    P.close()
    P.join()

CLIENT.auth.logout(KEY)
```

When I run the code I am getting following error,

```
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-348.12.1.el5 PoolWorker-1
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-348.18.1.el5 PoolWorker-8
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5 PoolWorker-9
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 PoolWorker-10
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 PoolWorker-3
<type 'str'> 2.6.9-100.ELsmp PoolWorker-8
<type 'str'> 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5 PoolWorker-4
<type 'str'> 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 PoolWorker-2
<type 'int'> 1 PoolWorker-11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1rhnGroupMaintenance.py", line 42, in <module>
    P.map(ADD_SYSTEMS, ACTIVESYSTEMS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
<type 'str'> 2.6.9-100.ELsmp PoolWorker-1
```

If I comment if..elif..else block in the function then print shows right values. I am clueless what am I doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with the limitation on Red Hat Satellite API calls in version 5.4.1 at one point in time. I didn't find any Red Hat official documentation about this limitation but when I tested with 2 workers and the code worked just fine. I was running the code from my workstation with 12 CPU cores which Satellite API could handle and returned 1 for some of the calls. I will have to hard code the number of worker process.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see during the loop the value of `RUNNINGKERNEL` is `int` for one case:

```
<type 'int'> 1 PoolWorker-11
```

And you're trying to use `str.startswith` on that integer which is wrong.

```
>>> (1).startswith

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    (1).startswith
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

To fix this you can check the type of `RUNNINGKERNEL` and based on that add some new conditions.

```
if isinstance(RUNNINGKERNEL, int):
   #do something
elif isinstance(RUNNINGKERNEL, str):
   if RUNNINGKERNEL.startswith("2.6.32"):
      ...
```

Comment: I need to understand why I am getting value 1 there. If I run just the print statement not if..elif..else block then I get all the string values. What is causing the RUNNINGKERNEL value to return 1?

Comment: @SumitGoel No idea about that, may be the call to `addOrRemoveSystems` inside the if-elif blocks is causing that issue.

Comment: Actually getting the error before that call. Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this remote procedure call

```
RUNNINGKERNEL = CLIENT.system.getRunningKernel(KEY,SYSTEMID)
```

is sometime returning a string ("kernel something")  and for a specific key is returning an int (1)

Trying to use `startswith` on an int fails as it's a string method

I would check the actual answer for the remote procedure call on the culprit id or if the answer is expected, make sure you actually deal with a string

```
RUNNINGKERNEL = str(CLIENT.system.getRunningKernel(KEY,SYSTEMID))
```

or handle explicitely the case of an int:

if isinstance(RUNNINGKERNEL,int):
      pass
   else isinstance(RUNNINGKERNEL,str):
      # your bunch of ifs

Comment: It seems the problem is with the limitation on Red Hat Satellite API calls in version 5.4.1. I had to hardcode the worker processes to 2 and it worked just fine. Appreciate your response!